# Concatenating multiple text files into a single file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

What is the quickest and most pragmatic way to combine all *.txt file in a directory into one large text file?

Currently I'm using windows with cygwin so I have access to BASH.

Windows shell command would be nice too but I doubt there is one.

Answer (score 771, accepted):

This appends the output to all.txt

```
cat *.txt >> all.txt
```

This overwrites all.txt

```
cat *.txt > all.txt
```

Comment: you may run into a problem where it cats all.txt into all.txt... I have this problem with grep sometimes, not sure if cat has the same behavior.

Comment: @rmeador yes, that is true, if all.txt already exists you will have this problem.  This problem is solved by providing the output file with a different extension, or moving all.txt to a different folder.

Comment: cat *.txt >> tmp; mv tmp all.txt (and make sure that all.txt does not exist beforehand)

Comment: I get "Argument list too long" -- guess it can't handle 40,000+ files.

Comment: Avoid argument list too long with: `echo *.txt | xargs cat > all.txt`

Comment: You will get some garbage in between if any files doesn't terminate with empty new line.

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. Must make sure though that all input .txt files end with a blank newline.

Comment: Is there a simple way to add an extra newline between each file?

Comment: @MaxCandocia `sed -i -e '$a\' filename.txt` will append one new line to filename.txt. `find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 8 sed -i -e '$a\'` will do that for all txt files in the current folder (set P to the number of your logical processors and it will do that concurrently using all your threads).

Comment: How do we add a demiliter in between the files ?

Comment: to make sure that an empty amount of input files will create a new file (or better say remove any old file that was in place upfront) you can do a 'echo -n "" > all.txt' befor doing the operation mentioned above.

Answer (score 212):

Just remember, for all the solutions given so far, the shell decides the order in which the files are concatenated. For Bash, IIRC, that's alphabetical order. If the order is important, you should either name the files appropriately (01file.txt, 02file.txt, etc...) or specify each file in the order you want it concatenated.

```
$ cat file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 > out.txt
```

Answer (score 33):

The Windows shell command [`type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type) can do this:

```sh
type *.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Type `type` command also writes file names to stderr, which are not captured by the `>` redirect operator (but will show up on the console).

Comment: Just be aware that if you put the output file in the same directory as the original file it will cause a duplication because it will also combine the new output file twice.

Comment: user requested for bash

Answer (score 30):

You can use Windows shell `copy` to concatenate files.

```
C:\> copy *.txt outputfile
```

From the help:

> To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).

Comment: This as the IMHO cleanest solution with basically no side effects that beginners could trip over unfortunately does not get appreciated enough :-(

Comment: OP asked for Bash.

Comment: Did you read the question? "Windows shell command would be nice too..."

Comment: Worked pretty well, except at the very end of my file I got a weird SUB special unicode character. Deleting it is pretty easy programmatically but not sure why that happened.

Answer (score 19):

Be careful, because none of these methods work with a large number of files. Personally, I used this line:

```
for i in $(ls | grep ".txt");do cat $i >> output.txt;done
```

EDIT: As someone said in the comments, you can replace `$(ls | grep ".txt")` with `$(ls *.txt)`

EDIT: thanks to @gnourf_gnourf expertise, the use of **glob** is the correct way to iterate over files in a directory. Consequently, blasphemous expressions like `$(ls | grep ".txt")` must be replaced by `*.txt` (see the article [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

**Good Solution**

```
for i in *.txt;do cat $i >> output.txt;done
```

Comment: Why not `for i in $(ls *.txt);do cat $i >> output.txt;done`?

Comment: Mandatory [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) link, together with a downvote (and you deserve more than one downvote, because `ls | grep` is a seriously bad antipattern).

Comment: Got an upvote from me because it allows for arbitrary testing/ operations by file name prior to output and it's quick and easy and good for practice.  (In my case I wanted: for i in *; do echo -e "\n$i:\n"; cat $1; done )

Comment: Wouldn't the `ls *.txt` fail if there are too many files (Argument list too long error)?

Comment: @Mandatory: ls *.txt | grep *.txt | awk '/*.txt/'     LOL

Answer (score 18):

How about this approach?

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} + >> output.txt
```

Comment: Since OP says the files are in the same directory, you may need to add `-maxdepth 1` to the `find` command.

Comment: Works great with a big number of files, where the accepted reply's approach fails

Comment: ah i wish i knew what this plus and double redirect signify...

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It will work properly in a shell script. Here is a similar method if you want output sorted: `sort -u --output="$OUTPUT_FILE" --files0-from=- < <(find "$DIRECTORY_NAME" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)`

Comment: This is a very flexible approach relying on all the strengths of the `find`. My favourite!  Surely `cat *.txt > all.txt` does the job within the same directory (as pointed out above). To me, however, becoming comfortably fluent in using `find` has been a very good habit. Today they're all in one folder, tomorrow they have multiple file-endings across nested directory hierarchies. Don't overcomplicate, but also, do make friends with `find`. :)

Answer (score 8):

the most pragmatic way with the shell is the cat command. other ways include,

```
awk '1' *.txt > all.txt
perl -ne 'print;' *.txt > all.txt
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer for most circumstances.  
If any text file without an empty new line, using all the above `cat` method will concatenate last line and first line from adjacent files.

Answer (score 3):

```
type [source folder]\*.[File extension] > [destination folder]\[file name].[File extension]
```

For Example:

```
type C:\*.txt > C:\1\all.txt
```

That will Take all the txt files in the C:\ Folder and save it in C:\1 Folder by the name of all.txt

Or

```
type [source folder]\* > [destination folder]\[file name].[File extension]
```

For Example:

```
type C:\* > C:\1\all.txt
```

That will take all the files that are present in the folder and put there Content in C:\1\all.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:
`cat [directory_path]/**/*.[h,m] > test.txt`

if you use `{}` to include the extension of the files you want to find, there is a sequencing problem.

Answer (score 1):

**The most upvoted answers will fail if the file list is too long.**

A more portable solution would be using [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

```sh
fd -e txt -d 1 -X awk 1 > combined.txt
```

`-d 1` limits the search to the current directory. If you omit this option then it will recursively find all `.txt` files from the current directory.
`-X` (otherwise known as `--exec-batch`) executes a command (`awk 1` in this case) for all the search results at once.

> Note, `fd` is not a "standard" Unix program, so you will likely need to [install](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#installation) it

Comment: `bash: fd: command not found`  It should be mentioned that **fd** is a package you must install yourself.

Comment: I did link to it in the answer, but I will be even more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

When you run into a problem where it cats all.txt into all.txt,
You can try check all.txt is existing or not, if exists, remove

Like this:

`[ -e $"all.txt" ] && rm $"all.txt"`

Comment: `cat *.txt > all.txt` `>` command  overwrites all.txt if it exists `>>` adds data to existing file

Answer (score -5):

all of that is nasty....

```
ls | grep *.txt | while read file; do cat $file >> ./output.txt; done;
```

easy stuff.

Comment: Eeek! Don't do that. Do `find . -iname "*.txt" -maxdepth 1 -exec cat {} >> out.txt \;`