# Mysql : How to run batch of sql scripts from a folder

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a folder with o lot of sql scripts. I want to run all of them without specifying names of them. Just specify a folder name. Is it possible?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can not do that natively, but here's simple bash command:

```
for sql_file in `ls -d /path/to/directory/*`; do mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < $sql_file ; done
```

here `USER`, `PASSWORD` and `DATABASE` are the corresponding credentials and `/path/to/directory` is full path to folder that contains your files.

If you want to filter, for example, only `sql` files, then:

```
for sql_file in `ls /path/to/directory/*.sql`; do mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < $sql_file ; done
```

Comment: Here is why `ls` might be bad as listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2152795/1896134

Please look at momer's comment.
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: The `ls` command as it was previously written wasn't functional. It would list off the files in the directory but without the `/path/to/` prefix, thus it wouldn't run anything.

Answer (score 2):

That was what worked for me:
1. Created a shell script in the folder of my scripts

```
for f in *.sql
  do
   echo "Processing $f file..."

   mysql -u user "-pPASSWORD" -h HOST DATABASE < $f

 done
```