# How to concatenate JavaScript files without a build tool?

Tags: bash, concatenation

In bash without using Ant, Grunt or similar, I want to concatenate some files.

I don't think is should be harder than a few lines of bash.

I don't want to use a build tool as they do in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301442/how-do-i-concatenate-javascript-files-into-one-file).

I want to use bash similar to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150614/bash-shell-scripting-combining-txt-into-one-file).

It would be something like:

```
cat *.js > all.txt
```

However, I want to only cat .js files that have this form

```
object.SomeName.js
```

As a side question, do most people break out their .js into objects?

What about:

```
cat object.*.js >> all.txt
```

Also there are dependencies between the objects, so ordering matters.

What ordering does cat work in?

Comment: sounds like you just need to readup on wildcard file matching in bash...

Comment: I posted what I think is the answer, but b.c. there are depeddencies, I need to know the order that cat works in or perhaps there is a batter bash tool?

Comment: This answer: http://serverfault.com/a/122743 says bash wildcard expansion is alphabetical.

Comment: you can add a prefix to depends to ensure that alpha order is the correct order.

Comment: well I have dependencies, so I don't think I should do this.  I would have to come up with a naming convention to assure the order.  For example if obj2 needs obj0 and obj1, I would need to make sure they were loaded first.

Comment: If you use ES6, JavaScript itself has a syntax to `import` dependencies so scripts can define a partial ordering of the files required for them to work. I'm using TypeScript partially for that feature, and other transpilers exist. I hate overcomplicated build tools also, but writing in "future JavaScript" has other big benefits and in x years the transpiler becomes unnecessary when everyone updates their engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a file that describes your dependencies.

```
obj0 obj2
obj1 obj2
```

Now `tsort(1)` can give you an ordering.

```
$ tsort dep.txt
obj0
obj1
obj2
```

Now you can read each line in turn and output the files in the correct order.

```
{
  while read obj
  do
    cat "object.$obj.js"
  done < <(tsort dep.txt)
} > all.js
```

Comment: Here is a nice explanation of tort - https://viget.com/extend/dependency-sorting-in-ruby-with-tsort - It uses a dependency hash.  Can i write dep. txt  in JSON ?  Or is it just space separated like in your example.

Comment: @cadegalt: As the man page explains, the input file is whitespace-delimited.