# Combine multiple text file into one with Bash

Tags: bash

In a folder I have multiple text files, suppose:

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt

I use this script, saved in the same folder, to combine the content of that files into one,

```
if [ -a ALL.txt ]; then
rm ./ALL.txt
fi

for i in *.txt; do 
mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g'`"; 
done;

for f in *.txt; do
echo '' >> "$f"
done

for i in *.txt; do 

cat $i >> ./ALL.txt

done
```

but this script adds one new line at the end of each file every time I run it. How to avoid it?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: `echo '' >> "$f"` adds a new line at the end of each file, so if you don't want that, I'm wandering what this is supposed to do...

Comment: Do you just want to `cat *.txt > ALL.txt`?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, it is probably already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150614/bash-shell-scripting-combining-txt-into-one-file

Comment: you are right. thank you.