# How do I concatenate file contents into a single file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have files in different directories under a parent directory, something like this:

- Parent Dir

  - Dir 1 - File 1
  - Dir 2 - File 2

I want to have an output file that appends the content of File1 with File2. How do I do it in Bash?

Comment: `find /parentDir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat > singleFile`

Comment: It goes in an infinite loop @anubhava

Comment: `cat dir1/file1 dir2/file2 > newfile`

Comment: @anubhava It worked, find home -name "*.orc" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > test.orc

Comment: @anubhava The reason was that I was saving it in the same directory where it was reading from, so the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer. You can use following `find + xargs` pipeline command:

```
cd /parent/dir

find home -name "*.orc" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > test.orc
```

Comment: The question seem like a dup of [Concatenating multiple text files into a single file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2150614/608639).