# concatenating files in python

Tags: python, numpy, glob

I have files in a directory and i want to concatenate these files vertically to make a single file.

```
input

file1.txt   file2.txt
1              8
2              8
3              9
```

i need output

```
1
2
3
8
8
9
```

My script is

```
import glob
import numpy as np
for files in glob.glob(*.txt):
    print(files)
    np.concatenate([files])
```

but it doesnot concatenate vertically instead it produces last file of for loop.Can anybody help.Thanks.

Comment: Why are you introducing numpy in your code?

Comment: @C.Pappy i am confused please help.I just want to concatenates the 1d arrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating multiple text files into a single file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150614/concatenating-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-file-in-bash) (Assuming you are bash. Python/numpy & co are not required for this task, as described).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code,
Numpy appears a bit **overkill** for such a mundane task in my opinion. You can use a much simpler approach, like for instance:

```
import glob

result = ""
for file_name in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        
        for line in f.readlines():
            result += line
print(result)
```

In order to **save the result** in a **.txt-file**, you could do something like:

```
with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to save it to a text file?

Comment: sure, I'll update the answer quickly for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
import glob

for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    fileopen = open(r"" + files, "r+")
    file_contents = fileopen.read()
    output = open("output.txt", "a")
    output.write(file_contents)
    output.close()
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to save it to a text file

Comment: @bijay edited answer to save to file.