# Concatenate multiple log files into one single file to automate debug package generation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

Here are the files in my folder:

```
messages        
messages.1      
messages.2      
messages.3      
messages.4      
messages.5      
messages.6      
messages.7
```

I want to merge this files in one single file(e.g. log.txt) so that it is in this way:

```
messages.7 -> messages.6 -> messages.5 -> messages.4 -> messages.3 -> messages.2 -> messages.1 -> messages
```

I was manually executing cat commands i.e.

```
cat messages.7 >> log.txt
cat messages.6 >> log.txt
cat messages.5 >> log.txt
cat messages.4 >> log.txt
cat messages.3 >> log.txt
cat messages.2 >> log.txt
cat messages.1 >> log.txt
cat messages >> log.txt
```

I want to write a bash script which can handle any number of files.

FYI: messages is file with latest logs and messages.7 is the oldest.

Also, I do not want to reverse the content of the file. Number of files are dynamic and follows the same numbering patterns.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150614/concatenating-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-file-in-bash?rq=2

Comment: Actually, to do this manually, you can do it in a single statement: `cat messages{.{7..1},} >total_messages`.

Comment: @user1934428 Number of file is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point of the answer is to use a properly crafted `sort` command for file names. For the given filename pattern `messages[.N]` the command would be:

```
sort -t . -k 2 -n -r
```

`-t . -k 2` allows to sort by the numeric suffix, `-n` actually instructs sort to make 2 < 10, `-r` reverses the order of the output.

So you can use something like this to check the order of files:

```
ls -1 messages* | sort -t . -k 2 -n -r
```

... and to actually get the concatenated output in 'total_messages':

```
ls -1 messages* | sort -t . -k 2 -n -r | xargs cat > total_messages
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that this would also include a, say, file `messages.zip`. I guess you can restrict the glob pattern to include only those files with numeric extension, by using extended globbing.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 main difficulties:

1. List only the files you want, no more: use the `extglob` and `nullglob` bash options.
2. List them in a portable way (`ls` is not recommended for scripting): use regular pathname expansion.
3. Sort them in reverse numeric order of extension: use `sort`.

You can try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob
m=( messages?(.+([0-9])) )
printf '%s\n' "${m[@]}" | sort -t. -rnk2 | xargs cat >> log.txt
```

With the `extglob` option of bash `messages?(.+([0-9]))` expands as `messages` (if the file exists) and all existing `messages.n` files where `n` is a string of one or more digits. We store the file names in array `m`, print its content and pipe to `sort` with the `-t.` (use `.` as field separator) and `-rnk2` (reverse, numeric, second field) options.

The `nullglob` bash option takes care of the case where none of the files exist (without `nullglob` the pathname expansion produces the `messages?(.+([0-9]))` pattern itself, which causes an error because no such file exists).

Answer (score 1):

Strange that 7 is the oldest, but anyway....

`` cat `ls -r messages*` >total_messages ``

or I might suggest using timestamps...

`` cat `ls -t messages*` >total_messages ``